How to remove the bottom seal on a 9100 series Wayne Dalton door?
I can't get the bottom seal off the door. Anyone know where the dimples are located that are holding the seal in place and how to get the seal off the door? I can't find any youtube videos that show this.
I can only find a video on how to replace the whole bottom metal retainer. I am trying to just replace the black bottom seal. Also, it is not universal, you have to buy WD's specific seal.


What's wrong with removing the retainer to check for the dimples? You may find that it's a slide-in rubber.
